# Tkinter, button click with if Statement for a specific picture in a label

Tags: python, image, if-statement, random, tkinter

I'm trying to do a quiz with 4 pictures given randomly (only one at a time in a label). Below there are 4 buttons which are the answer options. The buttons always stay the same, just the pictures change randomly after answering the right question. So when there is a picture, after pressing the right button the picture should change into another one. If pressing the wrong button, nothing should happen.

So far, the problem is at referring to the picture which is seen at the moment in the right way.

Right now, I tried to change the picture into the next one after answering correctly, because I didn't know how to insert a random change.

Thanks for every help!

```html
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

Fenster = Tk()
Fenster.title('training')
Fenster.geometry('1024x720')

# images
img110 = PhotoImage(file='1.gif')
img120 = PhotoImage(file='2.gif')
img130 = PhotoImage(file='3.gif')
img140 = PhotoImage(file='4.gif')

# Label image
bild=randint(1,4)
if bild==1:
    labelbild = Label(image=img110)
elif bild==2:
    labelbild = Label(image=img120)
elif bild==3:
    labelbild = Label(image=img130)
elif bild==4:
    labelbild = Label(image=img140)
labelbild.place(x=350, y=150)

#actions

def button110Click():
    if  bild==1:
        labelbild.config(image=img120)
    else:
        pass

def button120Click():
    if bild==2:
        labelbild.config(image=img130)
    else:
        pass

def button130lick():
    if bild==3:
        labelbild.config(image=img140)
    else:
        pass

def button140Click():
    if bild==4:
        labelbild.config(image=img110)
    else:
        pass

# Buttons
button110 = Button(master=Fenster, text='108', bg='#D5E88F', command=button110Click)
button110.place(x=350, y=420, width=40, height=40)
button120 = Button(master=Fenster, text='120', bg='#FFCFC9', command=button120Click)
button120.place(x=440, y=420, width=40, height=40)
button130 = Button(master=Fenster, text='128.57', bg='#FBD975', command=button130Click)
button130.place(x=530, y=420, width=40, height=40)
button140 = Button(master=Fenster, text='135', bg='#FBD975', command=button140Click)
button140.place(x=620, y=420, width=40, height=40)

Fenster.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.  Is it the rendering, or the choosing of a random picture, or what?  Please state in simple clear sentences the sequence of events (you have a good start at it).  When you get to the problem part, explain exactly what happens and what's wrong and what you need to have happen instead.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yea sorry i try to point out the problem:

originally i had this at the buttonclick part:

def button110Click():
    if  Label(image=img110):
        labelbild.config(image=img120)  
    else:
        pass

def button120Click():
    if Label(image=img120):
        labelbild.config(image=img130)
    else:
        pass

and so on

so if i use this term  if Label(image=img120): it doesnt recognize the picture that is shown at the moment. I need a term that refers to what picture is shown at the moment to then to a different action for the click

Comment: the code for the click i had in the question, does obviously just recognize the first picture and not futher

Comment: OK, that helps, but please edit your post to include that information, as clearly and succinctly as possible, to get the best chance of getting an answer to your question.  If my answer below solves it, just remember this advice for next time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a list to hold the images, and use `bild` as the index into this list.

```
from random import randint
import tkinter

# number of images
N = 4

# Use a Python 'list comprehension' to build a list of images
images = [ PhotoImage(file='%d.gif') % i for i in range(1,N+1)]

bild = 0

def new_image():
    # Select and display the an image
    global bild
    bild = randint(0,N-1)
    labelbild = label(images[bild])
    labelbild.place(x=350, y=150)

new_image()

# actions
# (I bet there's a parametric way to do this using one function, but I don't know tkinter)

def button110Click():
    if bild == 0:
        new_image()

def button120Click():
    if bild == 1:
        new_image()

def button130Click():
    if bild == 2:
        new_image()

def button140Click():
    if bild == 3:
        new_image()

# The rest is the same as in the OP.
```

Since I don't have tkinter I was unable to test the complete application, so there may be bugs.